# I don't know what is producing the gigabytes of error in syslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog

The error is showing itself like this:

```
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Jan 11 16:39:52 pop-os org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error:
```

It has consumed my whole SSD.

Comment: You might like to post version of pop-os, version of Nautilus, whether you took updates recently, whether this used to work and then went bad, what hardware, and any config files you can find. pop-is is debian derivative, so you might find more directed support on those specific sites. Just google your whole error message (except the timestamp). Follow any reference to Nautilus, popup or debian.

Comment: Meanwhile, I would suggest not starting up nautilus, and using command line to remove any huge syslogs.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant , i have googled but was not able to find anything useful.

Comment: my syslog file is approx 50 gb. even after truncating it regrows . after sometime.

Comment: Nautilus is your GUI file manager. It is clearly continuously failing, and the 1514 in the message is the process id (this will be different every time it starts). You can kill this process from the command line, and tail the syslog to prove it has stopped growing. Then don't start it again until you install a better version of Nautilus, or fix this one, or use a different file manager. It may be auto-restarted, in which case you have to fix that (maybe find the binary of nautilus and rename it). You could boot from a live DVD to do any fixes.

Comment: @shivankanchal Have you considered using  [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the error is caused by VLC. Try using another Media Player.

Comment: It was the same for me: -> ll ~/.local/share/sddm/xorg-session.log  -> 77G -> vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided. -> VLC + nvidia drivers causes this.

Comment: +1. I had same problem -> had only 10GB of free space on root directory and file syslog took it all. This error was duplicating org.gnome.Nautilus[1812]: [00007f5fa8093aa0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
What caused it I had VLC with movie opened. I locked PC and went out of home, when I returned PC went sleep and after I woke it I saw a message that there is no space on root directory.

Comment: There is no need to use another player, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585714/137608).

Answer (score 14):

There is a bug filed for this large `/var/log/syslog` at
[Having a video playing/paused when switched to another user generates gigabytes of error logs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374).
In the bug description, it is mentioned that using a video player (e.g., VLC) is a way to pop the error. It is not clear if VLC is the only player that produces the error.

The bug was not solved.
But as a way to stop the output, closing VLC apparently works.
As per messages in the bug thread, and my own experience, avoiding having a playing video while switching users, and perhaps workspaces, should prevent the issue from appearing.
The [answer by nyxee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584246/137608) is a related workaround.

Answer (score 6):

"Paul_Pedant, I have googled but was not able to find anything useful".

I googled "org.gnome.Nautilus[1514]: [00007fa4fc465ce0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided" and up popped four helpful posts.

Two of them concern syslog messages about "invalid handle value", and other two about "AssertionMessage: *** Error in `nautilus': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0993d258 ***". Those are probably the same root cause, because a pointer to free() is just a handle too. If Nautilus is corrupting its own memory, no telling what junk comes out.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374

Having a video playing/paused when switched to another user generates gigabytes of error logs. syslog messages about "invalid handle value"

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1238993

nautilus assert failure: *** Error in `nautilus': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc7ec3a8800 ***

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1266766

nautilus assert failure: *** Error in `nautilus': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0993d258 ***

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/disabling-nvidia-driver-logging-errors/20258

Disabling nvidia driver logging errors

Maybe you should answer my detailed questions, or just uninstall and reinstall Nautilus, or check your versions against these bug reports, or file a bug on one of these sites. I don't have pop-os or Nautilus or Ubuntu or nvidia or a problem, so I can't investigate this further.

Answer (score 6):

It is caused by VLC if it is started by doubleclick on a file in Nautilus.

If your system suspends while VLC is still open, it will cause this problem. You can close VLC or just jump to another time location in the video then the log-spam will stop. The bug is already reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374).

### Workaround

1. After Suspend, first open VLC and rewind a bit to stop the logging.
2. empty syslog and journalctl with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# deletes all but the last 1000 lines in syslog and vacuums journalctl down to 50 MB

LINES=1000
tail -n $LINES /var/log/syslog > /tmp/tmpfile
cat /tmp/tmpfile > /var/log/syslog
rm /tmp/tmpfile
service syslog restart
journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
logger syslog "emptied and service restarted; journalctl vacuumed down to 50 MB"
```

or [download the script from my gist](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/2fe1fef2ff7f5bdd60a88a835f0c5573#file-2-truncate_syslog-sh)

Save the script in `/usr/local/sbin/truncate_syslog.sh` and give it executable rights

Comment: As an alternative, you can also just remove the vlc lines from syslog with `sudo sed -i '/vlc.desktop/d' /var/log/syslog` (takes a bit of time, mine was 200GB).

Answer (score 5):

The bug is in VLC, which prints logs after resuming.
My workaround is a systemd service that kills VLC after resuming.
[Here it is on the Github](https://gist.github.com/Red-Eyed/0fdaae7876254dccf4396f33aa1a8875); this is what it looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kills VLC on resume in order to fix logging spam

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/killall vlc
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=syslog
After=suspend.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target sleep.target
```

Comment: Note:the ExecStart prefix "-" indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more wise to just [empty `/var/log/syslog` on resume](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/2fe1fef2ff7f5bdd60a88a835f0c5573#file-2-truncate_syslog-sh)? Maybe, you want to continue watching your movie after having a tea in the kitchen? :)

Comment: @rubo77 It wont help because the bug is that VLC constantly prints to syslog after resume. So if u clear it once, vlc will not stop printing.

Comment: @rubo77 Also, the problem is in VLC, so I don't want to get rid of my logs because of a bug in a 3rd party software

Comment: Ok. Then maybe better a dialogue after resume, that asks you if you want to close VLC and if not, warn about the logging and suggest to rewind a bit (rewinding a second fixes the bug)

Comment: This is perfect. Until the bug is fixed,  this should be the accepted one. Writing and then deleting Terabytes will kill SSDs

Answer (score 2):

When I started VLC from the command-line (terminal), all the error messages went there instead of filling up my disk.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me on pop os 20.04
Closing vlc and clearing syslog stopped it from filling up

Vlc is good to use, just don't let the system go to suspend or switch user when a video is paused. Nevertheless was having other issues with my install so I wiped.